# How can I change the encoding of a subtitle file?

Tags: encoding, subtitle, sublimetext

I have a subtitle .srt file. Is there an app which can change the encoding of this file.
(I guess it's encoding is Arabic(windows-1256) but vlc and MXPlayer didn't open it.)
The link of subtitle is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1odrm72lm975lw7/A.I.%20Artificial%20Intelligence%202001%20720p.srt?dl=0).

Comment: Is there a Apple product involved in this ?

Comment: @Buscar웃 My laptop is MacBook Air and I'm searching for an app or a way to do it.

Comment: If it is not asking to much, please provide the link to the subtitle file so we can check on it.

Comment: It seems to be in Arabic (DOS) encoding.  You could open in TextEdit and resave as UTF-8 or what ever you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I often use [this](https://subtitletools.com/convert-text-files-to-utf8-online) online converter to get my .srt in UTF-8, give it a try !

Comment: Your answer helped me in my work. But you didn't provide any application to do it. Maybe you can claim there is no such app. Then I figure it as an answer.

Comment: Well, as Tom Gewecke said you should be able to do it with TextEdit but I always had issue doing it (you can set this in TextEdit > Preferences > Open and Save > Plain Text Encoding > Opening/Saving). I find out this online converter much simpler !